# Android: Horizontal ListView

Tags: android

I have a task like this:
Assume I have a list of 28 items.
I want to display 5 items at a time in the screen horizontally.
When user touch and drag to the left, it will be update by the next 5 items.
When user touch and drag to the right it will be update by the previous 5 items.
I don't know how to do it.
I need help, please!

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1:

A combination of [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) and [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with horizontal orientation should work for you.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <!-- your items here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

### Solution 2:

If you are certain that you want the whole batch of items to get replaced, then you should go for [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this myself but try https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView

Unlike HorizontalScrollView this works with ListAdapters just like the traditional vertical ListView does.